# Autoscaling pods using google cloud metric like pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-kubernetes-engine

I am currently referring to google documentation for autoscaling using pubsub metric from stackdriver:
[Autoscaling Deployments with External Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling)

But, I am getting some error in deploying google sample config present in above link/config link: [Link to config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iIF5.png)

Error:  *error validating data: ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec.metrics[0]): unknown field "external" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta1.MetricSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false*

Looked around the web but was unable to find any reference to this error. I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like, There was a version error.

Previously i was using 1.9.7-gke.11  (Although note that this is default gke version right now )
Now with 1.10.9-gke.5 , Everything is working fine